# Migrating play Framework from 2.2 to 2.5. Its there a short way? Or 2.2-> 2.3 -> 2.4 -> 2.5

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.5

We have a play-java webapp. We're planning to migrate to play 2.5.

Is there a shortcut or do we have to go through multistep process.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do 2.2 -> 2.5 in one go but it may be quiet long since a lot of changes were done throughout the versions. Anyway, I would recommend you to read the migration guides to see how much it will impact your application and your code base:

- [2.2 -> 2.3](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration23) : Build and project changes mostly
- [2.3 -> 2.4](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration24) : Big changes with dependency injection
- [2.4 -> 2.5](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25) : Removes more of the `Global` stuff in favour of dependency injection

Comment: Thanks. I kind of went through the documentations links before posting and it looks like a painful process. So wanted to see if there's something which someone has done. Looks like painful is the way to go.

Comment: it's not as painful as you think.
I was on 2.3 and scala 2.10 on one app and the only "big change" was a library that didn't existed anymore.
And for the future I kept the following in my mind: Dependencies aren't free.
Actually most of our apps run on 2.5.x and the only one we didn't upgraded was a stable project on 2.3 behind a firewall. 
if you are on 2.3.x / 2.4.x you start running on a supported version.

Answer (score 1):

Just did that for a Java project. Took me one week of pain and sorrow.

The result? A code full of patches (to make it work with the new dependency injection system) that takes longer to compile and throws random out of memory exceptions if you try to compile it on VMs with less than 1GB of RAM (like the small EC2 instances from AWS).

I miss the lightweight and developer friendly framework that I fell in love with...

Comment: Can you please help me with the steps.I am really struggling.

Comment: you have to follow the Migration guides, one by one. Start with 2.2 -> 2.3, then 2.3 -> 2.4 and finally 2.4 -> 2.5. There is no shortcut. If you have issues along the way, post them here and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help with 2.2->2.4, since I started with 2.4.
There is a lot of API changed in 2.4->2.5. In case you will have issues with 2.4->2.5 look here for [practical tips](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/05/migration-play-24-to-play-25.html).

Comment: yup. It's not straightforward. So, I am planning to continue with 2.2 for a while. Thanks anyways